# Collapse rows by value in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have a dataframe of NBA player statistics scraped from basketball-reference.com like this one below:

```
Player       | Pos  | Team  | Games | Min   | Points

Alex Abrines |  SG  | OKC   | 68    | 15.5  | 6.0  
Quincy Acy   |  PF  | TOT   | 38    | 14.7  | 5.8  
Quincy Acy   | PF   | DAL   | 6     | 8.0   | 2.2  
Quincy Acy   | PF   | BRK   | 32    | 15.9  | 6.5  
Steven Adams |  C   | OKC   | 80    | 29.9  | 11.3  
Arron Afflalo| SG   | SAC   | 61    | 25.9  | 8.4
```

For players who have played the entire season for the same team (like Abrines, Adams, and Afflalo), they only appear once.  But if a player has played for more than 1 team (like Quincy Acy), the dataframe contains a row for each team he played for and then another "TOT" (total) row.

I'd like to get back a dataframe that only has 1 unique row per player, and that row being the "TOT" row and the other rows to be eliminated.  Kinda stumped.

The most sensible thing would be to do it by the row that has "TOT" in the Team column, but one thing that always will be true about the Total row for one of these players that has one is that the Games value will be higher than the Games values in the other rows for that player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a group by `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Player, Pos) %>%
    filter(Team == "TOT" | n()==1)
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   Player, Pos [4]
#        Player   Pos  Team Games   Min Points
#         <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1  Alex Abrines    SG   OKC    68  15.5    6.0
#2    Quincy Acy    PF   TOT    38  14.7    5.8
#3  Steven Adams     C   OKC    80  29.9   11.3
#4 Arron Afflalo    SG   SAC    61  25.9    8.4
```

---

Similar approach with `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[Team=="TOT"|.N==1], .(Player, Pos)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Player = c("Alex Abrines", "Quincy Acy", "Quincy Acy", 
"Quincy Acy", "Steven Adams", "Arron Afflalo"), Pos = c("SG", 
"PF", "PF", "PF", "C", "SG"), Team = c("OKC", "TOT", "DAL", "BRK", 
"OKC", "SAC"), Games = c(68L, 38L, 6L, 32L, 80L, 61L), Min = c(15.5, 
14.7, 8, 15.9, 29.9, 25.9), Points = c(6, 5.8, 2.2, 6.5, 11.3, 
8.4)), .Names = c("Player", "Pos", "Team", "Games", "Min", "Points"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```